# Не конвертирует файл в json. Python

Tags: python, requests

Есть не большой код:

```
base_url = 'https://piter-online.net'
i = '/leningradskaya-oblast/orders/home?tariff_id=102134004'
result = requests.get(base_url + i).json()
check_info = result.get("location")
print('Location:' + check_info)
assert check_info == i
print(f'Тестирование URL: {base_url + i} завершено успешно')
```

Выходит ошибка:
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Код ответа 200 в этом проблем нет.

Comment: И что, что код ответа 200? Вы пробовали распечатать результат? Ваш get запрос возвращает html код, который библиотека при всём желании не сможет преобразовать в json

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как тогда преобразовать из html в json?

Comment: Никак. Если вам необходимы какие-то конкретные данные оттуда, вы можете их самостоятельно спарсить с помощью, например, BeautifulSoup.